# EFCore Update isn't updating rows in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've got a payload coming up from my client that is an object whose properties are primitives and other objects whose properties are also primitives.

For example:

```
public class MainObj
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int id {get;set;}
   public string foo {get;set;}
   public OtherObj bar {get;set;}
}

public class OtherObj
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int id {get;set;}      
   public int test {get;set;}
}
```

Once I validate the request, I get the object the user is trying to update:

```
var obj = _context.MainObjs.Select(x => new MainObj
{
     id = x.id,
     foo = x.foo,
     bar = x.bar
}).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.id == request.id);
```

I'm doing the `.Select` because if I don't, then `bar` never gets populated.

Then I update the properties with what comes up from the client:

```
obj.foo = request.foo;
obj.bar = request.bar;
```

Then I try to save changes:

```
_context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

However, nothing is persisting in the database when I do this.  What am I doing wrong?  I've only worked with EF6 in the past, so I dunno if EFCore has something weird about updating objects with foreign key relationships.  And to be clear, my actual objects have many more properties than this, but I don't believe that's the problem.

EDIT:  I tried using `.Include` syntax instead of `.Select` , which looks like this:

```
var obj = _context.MainObjs.Include(x =>x.bar).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.id == request.id);
```

but then I get an error that  `The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked.`

EDIT2:  Replacing all of that other code with simply `_context.Update(request)` is working.  I'm curious why the other way isn't though.

Comment: I've also noted this behavior, from what i gathered it seems to be intentional. All the default generated code uses this way as well. Since your question is well stated, maybe you want to add your EDIT2 as an answer?

Comment: In your given code, you are calling `*Async` methods without `await` in front of it. Could that have been a problem?

Answer (score 2):

The statement ...

```
_context.MainObjs.Select(x => new MainObj { ... })
```

... doesn't attach anything to the context. It just creates a new `MainObj` object, but EF doesn't know about it. In EF6 it wasn't allowed to create entity types in EF LINQ queries, exactly to prevent this confusion.

So by using `_context.MainObjs.Include(x =>x.bar)`, you do attach a `MainObj` and its `bar` to the context and its changes will be tracked.

Finally, the statement `_context.Update(request)` attaches `request` to the context and marks it as `Modified`, including its foreign key to its `bar` property.